# Python Orange Numpy Examples

Tags: python, numpy, classification, orange

I am trying to take a recarray and import it into a [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/) ExampleTable. The recarray is coming from a odbc datasource and I would like to avoid saving it to a csv to import into orange.

I've hunted all around the orange and numpy documentation and the connection between the two seems vague.

Comment: Currently, only PostgreSQL and SQL Server databases are supported, see https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/data/sqltable.html.